# Java Problem with adding new elements to Map<Integer, List<Integer>>

Tags: java

I have Map <Integer, List> where Integer is key(building floor) , List is value with people on the floor.I need to add person to the List for the certain floor but i stuck with that cos when i tried to add person to floor List my Map updates all Lists to all Keys ;( I need some help pls

```
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : deliveredPassengerMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() == passenger){
                entry.getValue().add(passenger);
                }
            }
        System.out.println("=====Delivered Passenger Map=====");
        System.out.println(deliveredPassengerMap);
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to replace 'entry.getKey() == passenger' with 'entry.getKey() == certainFloor'

Comment: Rather than iterating the `Map` (which is a very slow lookup), you can simply use `Map#get` to retrieve the `List<Integer>` stored under the `passenger` key. It will either be a `List<Integer>` (if it exists) or `null` (if it doesn't). Otherwise, show more code of the surrounding problem.

Comment: I want to write evevator moving through the floors from up to down etc. So i need Map with unloaded passengers. I do Map<Integer, List<Integer> where key is floor List is persons who unload on the certain floor. So i cant correctly update List with passengers cos my code update all Lists for all Keys((( 
private final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> deliveredPassengerMap = new TreeMap<>();

Comment: So people are represented with `Integer` values, and you need `"moving through the floors from up to down"`, i.e. you want to remove a particular *person* from a list mapped to a particular floor and add them to an entry that corresponds to another floor?

Comment: I load passengers to the elevator then move to the certain floor. After i remove person who match destination floor from the elevator array and call method deliveredPerson(int passenger) to update Map deliveredPassngerMap. On this step i stuck cos i cant update only certain List. I got update of all List of the Map

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a simpler way to do this.

```
Optional<List<Integer>> floor = Optional.ofNullable(deliveredPassenger.get(flr));
floor.ifPresent(passengers -> {
  passengers.add(passenger);
  deliveredPassenger.put(flr, passengers);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Its work. But result is the same.
```
=====Delivered Passengers===== 
0:[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4] 
1:[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4] 
2:[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4] 
3:[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4] 
4:[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4] 
5:[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4] 
6:[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4] 
7:[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4]```

Comment: This code update all List of the map.
```private void deliveredPassengerMap(int passenger) {
        Optional<List<Integer>> floor = Optional.ofNullable(deliveredPassengerMap.get(passenger));
        floor.ifPresent(passengers -> passengers.add(passenger));
        System.out.println("=====Delivered Passenger Map=====");
        System.out.println(deliveredPassengerMap);
    }```

Comment: @Normat i'm updated, now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all guys. Problem was with initialization of Map. I had the same link to Lists for the keys. It was my false. I have to write put(i, new ArrayList<>()); instead put(i, list);

````
public void initUnloadPassengersMap(int buildingLevels) {
       for (int i = 0; i < buildingLevels; i++) {
           deliveredPassengerMap.put(i, new ArrayList<>());
       }
   }

   ```
````